# Is there a transitive set that is non empty and doesn't contain the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Sorry for being so naive and because this is maybe a silly question but all the examples I can think of contains the empty set, and it's not clear to me whether this makes sense at least intuitively.

For example, let's supose that we have a set $A\neq \emptyset$ that is transitive. Then there's $x\in A$. But then every element $x_{i}$ in $x$ is element of $A$.  Then every element $x_{j}$ of $x_{i}$ is in $A$. And so on.  This processes might be infinite and hopefully $A$ doesn't have the empty set...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming the Axiom of Foundation, no there isn't.  For example, assume $t \neq \emptyset$ is transitive.  Let $x$ be an $\in$-minimal element of $t$.  Then $x \cap t = \emptyset$. But since $t$ is transitive, $x \subseteq t$ so that $x = x \cap t = \emptyset$.

**Edit 1**: As you point out, possibly that chain of elements could be infinite, but the Axiom of Foundation says that $\in$ is well-founded and that is equivalent to saying that there is no descending chain $ \cdots \in x_1 \in x_0$.

**Edit 2**: As Andres points out below not assuming Foundation it is consistent that there is a set $A = \{ A \}$ i.e. $A \in A$ so that $A \neq \emptyset$.  But then $A$ is transitive because $\forall y \in A (y \subseteq A)$ ($A \in A$ and surely $A \subseteq A$). Relating this to my first edit, we would have a descending chain $ \cdots \in A \in A \in A$.

Comment: It is consistent with set theory without foundation that there is an $A$ such that $A=\{A\}$. I guess your question is whether the failure of foundation suffices to imply the existence of a counterexample.

Comment: Oh, well that set exactly works then, huh?  If $A = \{A\}$ then $A$ is transitive since the only element in $A$ is $A$ which clearly, we have $A \subseteq A$.

Comment: you may be interested in https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~mkysiak/files/papers/inttrans.pdf where they construct a model of set theory without the foundation axiom in which there exists a transitive set X st the  intersection of all of its elements is not transitive; obviously X does not contain ∅