# $X\subset \mathscr{P}(X)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a  not empty set. If $X\subset \mathscr{P}(X)$, what can we say about the set $X$?

For example: $$X=\{\emptyset\}$$ $$X=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$$ $$X=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$$

*approach*: I think the empty set must be an element of $X$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The property you're looking for is called transitivity: A set $X$ is called transitive if for all $x\in X$, we have $x\subseteq X$.

Comment: $X\subseteq X$ means $X\in \mathcal P(X)$, not $X\subseteq \mathcal P(X)$. @MathMajor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$X \subset \mathscr{P}(X)$ means that every element of $X$ is a subset of $X$, so $$\forall x \in X: \forall y \in x: y \in X$$ This means by definition that $X$ is a [transitive set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set), so called because the relation $\in$ is transitive on $X$, as expressed by this formula.

Comment: We can say that the empty set is always an element of $X$?

Comment: @felipeuni I don't think so, why do you think that? $X$ itself could be empty and the condition would hold.

Comment: but $X$ is not empty.

Comment: Maybe if you assume the axiom of regularity? Still I doubt it would hold.

Comment: See this:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434245/is-there-a-transitive-set-that-is-non-empty-and-doesnt-contain-the-empty-set

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. If $X$ is  not empty the axiom of Regularity (a.k.a. Foundation) says $\exists Y\in X \;(Y\cap X=\phi)$. But if $X$ is transitive then  $Y\in X \to Y\subset X \to  Y=Y\cap X.$

Comment: @user254665 so indeed $\emptyset \in X$ if we assume regularity.