# Is statement "for every set $A$: $\{A\}$ is transitive iff $A = \emptyset$" true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It seems to me that this is not true. Where should I start if I'd want to disprove that? Would that be enough to show that $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ is transitive?

Comment: Well, it is true, since $\{A\}$ has one element, and that element is not a member of $A$ by the axiom of regularity. Hence, there are no elements of $A$ which are elements of $\{A\}$, so the set can only be transitive if $A$ has no elements.

Comment: Showing that $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ is transitive won't help, because there is no set $A$ such that $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\} = \{A\}$ (the left side has two elements, the right side has one).

Comment: For a stronger statement see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434245/is-there-a-transitive-set-that-is-non-empty-and-doesnt-contain-the-empty-set

Comment: I see, thank you all

Comment: $\{\emptyset\}$ is transitive and not equal to $\emptyset$.