# For every non-empty transitive set A, show that ∅ is an element of A.

Tags: logic, set-theory

I want to know if this is a correct proof or not:

Suppose that ∅ is not an element of A. For any x,y such that y∈x and x∈A, the following preposition is True:

y∈x ∧ x∈A ⇒ y∈A

Take an arbitrary x∈A. Since ∅ is not an element of A, this implies that the truth-value of the following proposition is False :

x∈∅ ∧ ∅∈A ⇒ x∈A

But it is vacuously True, since x∈∅ is False.
So we have a contradiction and ∅∈A

Comment: If we suppose $x \in A$, due to the fact that $x \in \emptyset$ is F, we have $(F \land F ) \to T$ which is T

Comment: Btw `$...\wedge\, \emptyset \in A\implies x\in A$` will give you $...\wedge\, \emptyset \in A\implies x\in A$

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier since A is transitive, the condition for ∅ being an element of A is that x∈∅ ∧ ∅∈A ⇒ x∈A be True. ∅ is not an element of A, so the condition does not meet. so the statement is false for any x∈A.

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier the argument does not change if we remove "always" from it. Whether x is a variable or fixed, does not change the fact that x∈∅ is false and thus, the proposition is vacuously True.

Comment: No. What you are written is not a correct proof. For instance, if $\Omega=\{\Omega\}$, then $\Omega$ is transitive and $\emptyset\notin\Omega$, so any proof of the statement you want must use foundation. But your argument doesn't.

Comment: @ Andrés E. Caicedo explain it more, perhaps in an answer and tell me which part is wrong.

Comment: See the [following post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434245/is-there-a-transitive-set-that-is-non-empty-and-doesnt-contain-the-empty-set).

Comment: Mauro ALLEGRANZA I understand that. That's a right proof. But what's wrong with mine?

Comment: Your proof consists of two sentences. One of them is a definition, and the other has been criticized in all the comments

Comment: @Andrés E. Caicedosince:Read this previous comment carefully and tell me whats wrong with it, (if you read other comments, you will notice that the 
main discussion was about the word "always" and not about my second statement): A is transitive, the condition for ∅ being an element of A is that x∈∅ ∧ ∅∈A ⇒ x∈A be True. ∅ is not an element of A, so the condition does not meet. so the statement is false for any x∈A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is certainly false. Let's apply it to $\{A\}$ instead of $\varnothing$.

If $\{A\}\notin A$, then $x\in\{A\}\land \{A\}\in A\to x\in A$, but this is vacuously true, since $\{A\}\in A$ is false. So we have a contradiction and $\{A\}\in A$.

---

But this does not make sense. You started with $x\in A$ to begin with, so $p\to x\in A$ is always true anyway, regardless of the truth of $p$. And you argue that since $p=p_0\land p_1$, and $p_1$ is always false, then $p_0$ is always true.

But that's just not how it works.

To prove this claim you *must* rely on the axiom of foundation, which implies that there is a rank function for sets. Try to prove this by induction on the von Neumann rank of $A$.